# Filling all of an empty dataframe's rows or columns with a single series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a predefined data frame of size NxM (N rows and M columns), it is initialized with all NaNs.

Now say I have a series of size M, I want to fill all rows with that series. For example, if the series is of ints [3,4,5] where N=2, M=3, my resultant dataframe should be (I have included column and row indices):

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

Alternatively, say I have a series of size N, I want to fill all columns with that series. For example, if the series is of ints [10, 11] where N=2, M=3, my resultant dataframe should be (I have included column and row indices):

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 1 | 11 | 11 | 11 |

How do I do both of these operations in pure pandas without resorting to using something like `np.repeat` or `np.tile`?

Comment: Second output is not `N=3, M=2` for 2 columns, 3 rows?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Did I mess up my N and M somewhere? @jerzael

Comment: Fo second one. Seems swap `N, M`

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you are getting at. I keep N and M constant because the number of rows and columns is constant for my examples. I see in your solution you use transpose, but the end values of N and M should still be the same throughout both examples

Comment: hmmm, so need always decide if repeat per rows or per columns? So use solution 1 or solution 2? Because if for N=2, M=2 for `s = pd.Series([7, 2])` both solution working with 2 different ouputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html), last if necessary transpose ouput for second sample data:

```
s = pd.Series([3,4,5])
N = 2
M = 3

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(N), columns=range(M))

df[:] = np.broadcast_to(s.to_numpy(), (N, M))
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  3  4  5
1  3  4  5

s = pd.Series([10, 11])
N = 2
M = 3

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(N), columns=range(M))
df[:] = np.broadcast_to(s.to_numpy(), (M, N)).T
print (df)
    0   1   2
0  10  10  10
1  11  11  11
```

---

```
s = pd.Series([3,4,5])
N = 2
M = 3

df = pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(s.to_numpy(), (N, M)))
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  3  4  5
1  3  4  5

s = pd.Series([10, 11])
N = 2
M = 3


df = pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(s.to_numpy(), (M, N)).T)
print (df)
    0   1   2
0  10  10  10
1  11  11  11
```

Comment: I had no idea you could even use transpose on dataframes, this is very elegant. Could you also do ```df[:] = s``` for the first example in both blocks? I tried this out in a notebook and it seemed to work.

I am not sure how to apply this logic to the second example though, I think the only option is what you have in your answer for the second example.

Comment: @AdityaMehrotra - First part of solution is if necessary empty `NaN`s DataFrames. Second one is much btter, faster, because `df[:]` is not so fast like `pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(s.to_numpy(),...`

Comment: @AdityaMehrotra - and if need broadcast by `(N, M)` or `(M, N)).T` depends of input data and expected ouput if `M=N` working both solutions.

Comment: @jerzael You are right, I did not consider ```M=N```. I think for my use case, I will know whether to copy by row or by column if ```M=N```. In your solution with ```pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(...``` , the first will get me repeat in rows and the second will get me repeat in columns if ```M = N```. I can choose whichever I want to use. Thank you for the nice solution!

Comment: I also did not know  ```pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(s.to_numpy()``` was faster than ```df[:]```, which is very helpful as well, as I have been using ```df[:]``` many times before this.